# Watery whites of the egg

Tags: eggs, egg-whites

I moved from the US to beautiful Portugal a little over a year ago. I buy free range eggs, which are not refrigerated. The whites are so watery, that then almost never set, no matter how I cook them (I’ve been cooking eggs for 50 years, so it’s not a new thing for me). I started refrigerating the eggs, which helps a little for fried eggs, but not meringue, baking, or soft boiled eggs. Anything I can add, especially for baking? Cornstarch, maybe? It’s weird...

Comment: No first hand experience here, but maybe straining through a fine mesh strainer would help. Explained at Serious Eats, though they credit Blumenthal, and McGee. <https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2014/04/foolproof-poached-eggs-food-lab-recipe.html>

Answer (score 2):

Storing eggs in high temperatures and low humidity will speed up the ageing process and cause whites to become watery.

Try sourcing some eggs from another producer as another coop may have better conditions and therefore better quality eggs. In the summer, hens may lay eggs with watery whites even though they are kept in good conditions. The older the hen, the more likely the egg whites will be watery.

If you are trying to bake with the watery eggs, try reducing the liquid ingredient by a tablespoon for each egg in the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Here in Australia we've been told that watery egg whites means they are not fresh eggs. Maybe you need to see if you can get them from a more local producer. Good luck.

Comment: Sure, older eggs have watery whites when raw, but the OP says their eggs don't turn solid when cooked, and that's not true for simply old eggs, their whites get perfectly firm with temperature.